# Import file with repeated column names for each individual R

Tags: r, import, tidyverse, tidy, data-wrangling

I have to import an unorthodox file into R. I've attached a small example file with fake data to demonstrate the issue. The raw data that I need to wrangle is shown in the image "raw" and the tidied data that I'm looking to create are shown in the image "tidy".

RAW
[image]

TIDY
[image]

Each individual has (1) group level information that applies to all individuals within the same group and (2) individual level information that only applies to the respective person. In the attached file, group level data includes **Family** and **Location**.  Then, there are repeating sets of columns that pertain to each individual depending on how many people belong in the group.

For example, line 2 represents the Smith family that lives in Chicago.  The Smith family has 3 members, including John, Sally, and Ben. Each member has their own set of repeating column names with the same information types: **Name**, **Age**, **Gender**, **Hobbies**. Each of these sets of columns have identical names and are repeated for up to a maximum of 3 individuals per family (9 total columns).

What I need is to import this data into R and transform it into a tidy format, ideally using a tidyverse solution.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the best strategy may depend also on how you input your raw data (e.g., from Excel).

If you happen to have Excel data, you can use `read_excel` from `tidyverse` and can include `.name_repair = "minimal"` to prevent changes in column names.

In this case, with `repair_names` you can have a consistent structure to column names that are repeated, perhaps with an underscore (this would give you `Name`, `Name_1`, `Name_2`, `Age`, `Age_1`, `Age_2`, etc.).

Finally, `pivot_longer` of your repeated columns would provide a tidy data frame.

Also, there are a number of alternative ways to fix your repeating column names and make unique; for example, `make.unique` called on `names(df)` or `clean_names(df)` from `janitor` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

df <- read_excel("raw_data.xlsx", .name_repair = "minimal")

df %>%
  repair_names(sep = "_") %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Family, Location), names_to = c(".value", "variable"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  select(-variable)
```

Comment: This works well.  The only bit I needed to add was a filter statement to remove cases where "Name" had missing info.  After that, the result is identical to `tidy` image above. Thank you!